# Sequence which satisfy division conditions and grows "slowish"

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divisibility

I have been playing around with prime numbers and I was wondering is someone knew of a sequence(s) that satisfy my conditions.  The conditions are:

1. $$F(N) > N$$
2. $$F(N) \neq N^x \text{ for all integers $N$, for any integer x}$$
3. $$F(N) \text{ never divides } F(P) \text{ for prime $P$ and $N < P$}$$

I know of some sequences/functions that satisfy these conditions. One such example of a function is the Mersenne numbers: $F(N)=2^N-1$, which grows at an exponential rate of about 2.  I also know of the Fibonacci sequence which grows at a rate of $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

I am particularly looking for examples where $F(N)$ either grows sub-exponentially or a small exponential.

The reason for the 2nd condition is that without it you can easily generate functions that satisfy #1 and #3.

If you have any examples of other sequences or questions please comment them below.

PS: If you are going to downvote for some reason, please post a comment saying why.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What's the range for $N$? If $N=1$ is a possibility then $F(N)=2^N-1$ will fail all three conditions at $N=1$.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the conditions. #2 means that there is no $x$ such that $F(N) = N^x$ for all $x$? So if $F(5) = 125$ but $F(N)$ isn't always $N^3$, is that allowed?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Any range you want is allowed.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp  $F(5)=125$ is allowed as long as it's not $F(N)=N^3$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want the sequence to possibly have infinitely many primes. 
 I just realized that there is a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944131/slowest-growing-divisibility-sequence?rq=1 but my question is slightly different

Comment: In that case, you could do something slightly more interesting than $N^x$, like for example $F(N) = N^{\lfloor \log N\rfloor}$.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, $F(N)=2N$ would satisfy your conditions.

Comment: $F(n) = p_n$ the $n$-th prime number hold for all three conditions and sub-exponential in growth, and have infinitely many primes.

Comment: @Ahmad, the reason I'm doing this is to find numbers possibly prime, and as such doing that is technically correct but it'd be much better if you had something like $\text{floor}(1.1^x + 13)$ or something.  That was a good idea though. :)